# what's the correct way to add counter inside flip-flop?

Tags: verilog, flipflop

I want to count number of "clock enable" signal inside flip flop.

I learn from tutorials that the output value should be assigned for all combinations of input.

However I don't know how to add counter that counter should be updated only if clk_enable = 1.

Please advise.

```
module count_ce (
  input logic reset_n, 
  input logic clk, 
  input logic clk_enable,
  output logic[63:0] counter
);

always_ff @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n) begin
  if (!reset_n) begin
    counter <= 64'd0;
  end else begin
    if (clk_enable) begin
      counter <= counter + 1;
    end else begin
      //counter <= counter; // ?
      counter <= 64'd0; // have to assign counter for else-case otherwise infer latch?
    end
  end
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

> I learn from tutorials that the output value should be assigned for
>   all combinations of input.

This is true for combinational logic, but you certainly intend to implement edge-triggered sequential elements (flip-flops).

In case you use `always_ff` and/or `posedge clk`, there is no possibility to infer latches. You will certainly have flip-flops.

```
always_ff @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n) begin
  if (!reset_n)
    counter <= 64'd0;
  else begin
    if (clk_enable)
      counter <= counter + 1;
  end
end
```

The `always` block above is safe even if there is no `else` condition. The `counter` will increment if `clock_enable` is HIGH, it will preserve its value if `clock_enable` is LOW.

The following code has the same behavior, the `else` part is just redundant.

```
always_ff @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n) begin
  if (!reset_n)
    counter <= 64'd0;
  else begin
    if (clk_enable)
      counter <= counter + 1;
    else
      counter <= counter;
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you **do** want to infer a latch. More correctly, you want to infer 64 edge-triggered flip-flops. Since that is your intent, you do not need to have an action for all input cases, or you can use the statement where the current value of counter is just assigned back to counter.

Answer (score 0):

You code likes reasonable except:

1. You **can not** generate latches in an `always_ff` or `@(pos/neg edge` always statement. As such can/may drop the whole `else` section.
2. In fact here I would drop the `else` section because as soon as the `clk_enable` goes away your counter is reset and your count is lost.
3. Your counter is 64 bit which is a bit big. It limits your maximum operating speed. Even running at 3GHz it will take ~195 years to overflow.
4. It just looks a bit weird to have counter running since reset and not being able to clear or re-start it.